# Send message via Topic and Tokens

Tags: c#, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I'm trying to send a push message to all mobile units that hits a specific condition.

Based on this I get my tokens for the users that will receive the message.
I would also like to send the notifications to the people that has subscribed to this type of message.

Example: 
We have 4 different types of events.

So if the user fulfills the first condition we will get its Token. 
when we got the token. We also want to make sure the user has subscribed to receive this type of event. Is there a way to combine sending a message via Tokens and Topics?

Regards

Comment: You should probably record the subscriptions in the database, so that you can check if a user is subscribed to receive a certain event by querying the database. There's no way to combine sending via FCM tokens and topics.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i'll have to find another way to solve this

Comment: @Johan did you find any other way to solve this?